# Cypher Query not giving result

Tags: node.js, neo4j

I have my deatils of the login and password in the following two variables:

```
let username = req.body.username;
let password = req.body.password
```

Now I have written the cypher query to fetch the details from the database which matches with the entered username and password, but my query does not fetch any result, but the node of that username and password exists in the database.

The query is:

```
 session
        .run('Match (n:voters) WHERE n.id={idParam} AND n.password={passwordParam} RETURN n',{idParam:username,passwordParam:password})
        .then(function(result){
            result.records.forEach(function(record){
                    console.log(record);
            });
            })
```

Comment: Is the `n.id={idParam}` a neo4j ID or Id inside voters? consider using `id(n)` if Neo4j ID.

Comment: Can you try the same query from the Neo4j browser and share what's the result here?